# How do I assign a var into a Hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

How would I do this:

```
{:foo => ['foo', 'bar'] }
```

`foo` is an actual variable, which returns `123`. What I'm really trying to do is:

```
{:1234 => ['foo', 'bar'] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in a hash both the key and the value can be any object. You just need to make sure you're creating a valid object. `:1234` is not a valid symbol. You could use

```
x = {1234 => ['foo', 'bar']}
```

You would access the array using `x[1234]`.

On another note, if you want to use a symbol, it must begin with a character, not a digit:

```
x = {:poke => ['foo', 'bar']}
```

And you would access it using `x[:poke]`.

Most commonly the key is: `Fixnum`, `String` or `Symbol`, but not limited to them.

You could also have some abstract class which you created and use it as the key, but I never had the need for that; doesn't mean it's not practical.

Comment: You beat me to it for 4 minutes :)

Comment: @fguillen I didn't really bother providing any proof. So, your answer is probably a bit more accurate than mine. :)

Comment: All valid answers, but yea, `:1234` is not a valid symbol. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using:

```
{foo => ['foo', 'bar'] }
```

That will result in a hash element of:

```
{123 => ['foo', 'bar'] }
```

and can be accessed from the hash using either `123` or `foo`.

---

You can also play tricks on Ruby's Hashes:

```
foo = 123                    # => 123
{ foo => [1,2] }             # => {123=>[1, 2]}
{ :123 => [1,2] }
SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
{ :123 => [1,2] }
      ^
{ foo.to_sym => [1,2] }
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for 123:Fixnum

{ foo.to_s.to_sym => [1,2] } # => {:"123"=>[1, 2]}
{ :"123" => [1,2] }          # => {:"123"=>[1, 2]}
```

Comment: Ah, yours is more to the point. ~ Well, I'll leave mine anyway. Someone might find it "educational."

Answer (score 4):

I think **a number can't be a symbol** :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > :1
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

If you don't care to use a proper symbol you can do this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo = "wadus"
 => "wadus" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > { foo.to_sym => [1,2] }
 => {:wadus=>[1, 2]} 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > { foo.to_sym => [1,2] }[:wadus]
 => [1, 2]
```

Comment: A numeric string can be a symbol. You just have to use the right syntax like `:"123"` which is equivalent to `"123".to_sym` which in turn is functionally equivalent to `123.to_s.to_sym`.